# Dynamic Sidebars based on page name

Tags: customization, templates, sidebar

I would like to do a dynamic sidebar for my WordPress site, so it would pull in the correct Sidebar template based on the page title of the page.

So if I had 10 sidebars all named like this:

Sidebar Template Name: About
Sidebar Template Name: Contact
Sidebar Template Name: Jobs
Sidebar Template Name: Etc
Sidebar Template Name: Page1

So the Sidebar 'About' would appear on the About page, and the same for contact, etc...

Any idea How I would do this? Or Is there an alternative way on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
if( is_page() ) :
    $this_page = get_queried_object();
    if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( $this_page->post_title ) ) :
        echo 'No sidebar defined for this page title';
    endif;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to include different sidebars when creating new template

name a sidebar like  **sidebar-jobs.php** then when creating **template name: Jobs**, just call this sidebar like so

```
<?php get_sidebar('jobs'); ?>
```

create metabox and list all registered sidebars

```
<select>
  <?php foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] as $sidebar ) { ?>
 <option value="<?php echo ucwords( $sidebar['id'] ); ?>">
          <?php echo ucwords( $sidebar['name'] ); ?>
 </option>
```

then based on selected value - call selected sidebar

Comment: But then I will need a separate template for every separate sidebar page.

I have 1 template, multiple pages which will have multiple sidebar templates.

Comment: then you can create array, I updated my answer above

Comment: will this just give me a selector to select a sidebar for that page? If so this is spot on!

Comment: yes. it will. you need to make metabox for your page.php and place this <select> and that's it. I would recommend this metabox framework https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress    I used it for displaying taxonomies and all pages inside metabox... works very well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a live example from one of my sites:

```
if(is_page('about-us')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('main-sidebar');
}
if(is_page('contribute')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('page-sidebar');
}
if(is_front_page() && is_page('about-us')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('main-sidebar');
}
if(!is_front_page() && is_page('about-us')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('another-sidebar');
}

if(is_category('archive')) {
    dynamic_sidebar('archive-sidebar');
}
```

You can see various scenarios where I need different widgets.

Also, in functions.php, I have this code:

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array('name' => 'Homepage Sidebar'));
    register_sidebar(array('name' => 'Blog Sidebar'));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Main Sidebar'),
        'id' => 'main-sidebar',
        'description' => 'This sidebar is active on Homepage, Despre Noi, Directioneaza 2%, and individual profiles.'
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => __('Archive Sidebar'),
        'id' => 'archive-sidebar',
        'description' => 'This sidebar is active on Archive page.'
    ));
}
```